# How to use variable in a Oracle scheduled job?

Tags: sql, oracle

The following script ran in Oracle SQL developer. It will insert two rows into a table. However, when I put this script into a job under the scheduler tab in Oracle SQL developer, no row was inserted. When created the job, I used sys.Default_job_class, type of job is PL/SQL block.
Can someone help me to revise the script, so it can be run in a job? Thank you

```
define batchNo='123';
insert into TABLE_NAME (col1, col2, col3, col4) select col1, col2, col3, col4 from TABLE2 WHERE BATCH_NO = '&batchNo';
commit;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code so it's a PL/SQL block:

```
DECLARE
  batchNo  VARCHAR2(3) := '123';
BEGIN
  insert into TABLE_NAME (col1, col2, col3, col4)
    select col1, col2, col3, col4
      from TABLE2
      WHERE BATCH_NO = batchNo;
  commit;
END;
```

`define` and `&varname` are used in SQL*Plus, but are not valid PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax with "&batchNo" is specific to SQL*Plus. It will not work with PL/SQL.

PL/SQL would need something like this:

```
DECLARE
    l_batchno number := 123;
BEGIN
    insert into TABLE_NAME (col1, col2, col3, col4) 
        select col1, col2, col3, col4 from TABLE2 WHERE BATCH_NO = l_batchno;
    commit;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute with parameter you must do:

```
sqlplus -s $USER/$PASSWD @ script.sql <YOUR_PARAMETER>
```

Your SQL Script must contain:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (col1, col2, col3, col4) 
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM TABLE2 WHERE BATCH_NO = '&1';
COMMIT;
```

If you want to use more than 1 parameter...

```
sqlplus -s $USER/$PASSWD @ script.sql <PARAMETER_1> <PARAMETER_2> ... <PARAMETER_N>
```

You must put into script.sql

```
DECLARE
    v_FIRST DATATYPE;
    v_SECOND DATATYPE;
    v_N DATATYPE;
BEGIN
    v_FIRST := '&1';
    v_SECOND := '&2';
    v_N := '&N';
END;
```

Comment: Thank you for the information on using parameter